# How to know when the AsyncStorage in React-Native is Full?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to know when `AsyncStorage` is full in react native.

What do `Error` value we get when the `AsyncStorage` is full to react native or will something else happen?

We can get a value from `AsyncStorage` using the below code

```
try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
   } catch (error) {
     // Error retrieving data
   }
```

if someone can suggest me a check in the above code to know when `AsyncStorage` is full. It would be really helpful.

Comment: The size limit is indefinite for ios and 6MB for android, if you are using all the storage then you're method of using the storage space is probably wrong and you would need to optimize it.

Comment: @Pritish Vaidya I know but in my scenario the chances AsyncStorage getting full is very slim. But I wanted to take a precaution just in case it gets full i wanted to clear it.

Comment: There is no api to check as per the docs, but you won't run into that scenario, 6MB is a lot of space.

Answer (score -4):

Do the steps

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

AsyncStorage.setItem('Islogin', 'Yes');
```

And check that you have stored or not.

```
  _storeData = async () => {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Islogin');

      if (value) {
        if (value == 'Yes'){

           console.log("You are auto login");

        }else{
           console.log("abc");
        }
      }else{
           console.log("abc");
      }
    } catch (error) {
              console.log("error" + error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I needed to know when it gets full. Not that a value is stored or not

Comment: I don't know exact limit but there might be a 6mb limit in android. and in IOS your how disk is free depend on that.

Comment: He is asking how to know when the limit is full